# Returning records which only have one specific many to many relation

Tags: mysql

Given this structure

```
CREATE TABLE locations
    (`id` int, `Name` varchar(128))
;

INSERT INTO locations
    (`id`, `Name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Location 1'),
    (2, 'Location 2'),
    (3, 'Location 3')
;

CREATE TABLE locations_publications
    (`id` int, `publication_id` int, `location_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO locations_publications
    (`id`, `publication_id`, `location_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (3, 2, 2),
    (4, 1, 3)
;
```

I would like to find only Location 2 based on the fact that it has only one relation with a publication_id = 2.

It should not return location one due to the fact that it has two relation rows.

This is sort of what I'm looking for but of course dosnt work because it limits the relationship to where publication_id = 2.

```
select * from locations
join locations_publications on locations_publications.location_id = locations.id
where locations_publications.publication_id = 2
group by (locations.location_id)
having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select location_id
from locations_publications
group by location_id
having count(*) = 1
```

If a location might have multiple records with the same publication, change the `having` criteria to `count(distinct publication_id) = 1`

---

Given your edits, you can use conditional aggregation for that:

```
select location_id
from locations_publications
group by location_id
having count(*) = sum(case when publication_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: The problem would be if there was more data. If there was a record (4,1,3) then this fails because I only want locations_publications with id 3 to be returned

Comment: @hcker2000 -- huh?  Why wouldn't 2 get returned -- it still only has a single publication?  Perhaps you should edit your question to clarify your desired results.

Comment: I went ahead and added more data to my original question.

Comment: @hcker2000 -- but you haven't explained why id 2 would not be returned?  Your sample data would suggest 2 records don't have multiple publications.

Comment: Because there are two records with only one relationship. This one (3, 2, 2) and (4, 1, 3). I only want locations who have a single relationship whos locations_publications.publication_id = 2

Comment: @hcker2000 -- Assuming I'm understanding your question, I've edited my answer.  You can use `conditional aggregation` for that sort of query.

Comment: Thanks that is more like what I'm looking to do. I take it that case happens before the group by?